# How to get the response of form submit?

Tags: xml, forms, post, submit, response

i have this code in javascript wherein i can post successfully on the server.

```
$('<form>', {

"name": "postticket",

"method": "POST",

"html": 'input type="text" id="task_name" name="task[name]" value="' + model.subject + '" 

input type="text" id="submitted" name="submitted" value="submitted"',

"action": model.url

}).appendTo(document.body).submit()
```

The result of this one redirects me to a page containing the id of the newly data i have posted.

Now, what I want is to get the data of the page where i am redirected to when i hit the submit function.

How to do that? please help.

Note: special tags like < />are removed since it cannot be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

try to give a working format for your example code.

if i understand your question correct you just want to use the transfered data?

so it should be able to get it by $_POST['task']

try to do a var_dump($_POST) to see all transfered POST data and check if it contains the 'task' array.

Comment: no. i want the result after i post the values. that is, the id of the newly created task on the server. The api is expected to return a data the includes the id of the task, name of the task, and other details.